# How do you differentiate different variable in Definitions?

Tags: python, python-3.x

So I am trying to write a RPG game that has four different races and each of them has different stat modifiers. But I am still new to python, so I don't really know how to differentiate different races's stat modifier in Definitions, like Dexterity modifier +3 to dexterity or different HP 11 / 12. Other problems I am having are I want to have different weapons, but how to I implement it? The last thing is, how do you insert different enemy HP into the while loop?

```
import random
def atk():
    atk = random.randint(1, 20) + d
    return atk
def dmg():
    dmg = current.weapon + s
    return dmg
def battle()
    print('What will', name, 'do?')
    while hp > 0 and :
```

Comment: This sounds like a job for ***Classes*** and ***Inheritance***.

Comment: What's are Defs, HPs, and Dexterity modifiers?  Your question is unclear.

Comment: Defs are Definitions. Dexterity modifiers are the d applied at end of the attack definition, but different races have diferent dexterity modifiers. HPs are hit points.

Comment: i think what you are looking for is function arguments, using arguments you can pass different values to a function rather than using global variables